# ld: framework not found (homemade framework)

Tags: ios, xcode, frameworks

I'm trying to deploy a project on an Ipad, containing a homemade framework called "HelloUnity.framework".

When I try to deploy my project I get the following error :

```
ld: framework not found HelloUnity clang: error: linker command failed
with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

More specific :

```
Ld /Users/LabInnovation/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Unity-iPhone-akzhbmwtkcooizfaebdhmbyuhrbk/Build/Products/test.app/test normal armv7
    cd /Users/LabInnovation/IpadWii/IpadWii
    setenv IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET 2.2.1
    setenv PATH "/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/usr/bin:/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin"
    /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/clang++ -arch armv7 -isysroot /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS6.0.sdk -L/Users/LabInnovation/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Unity-iPhone-akzhbmwtkcooizfaebdhmbyuhrbk/Build/Products -L/Users/LabInnovation/IpadWii/IpadWii -L/Users/LabInnovation/IpadWii/IpadWii/Libraries -F/Users/LabInnovation/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Unity-iPhone-akzhbmwtkcooizfaebdhmbyuhrbk/Build/Products -F/Users/LabInnovation/IpadWii/IpadWii/../../Desktop -F/Users/LabInnovation/IpadWii/IpadWii -filelist /Users/LabInnovation/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Unity-iPhone-akzhbmwtkcooizfaebdhmbyuhrbk/Build/Intermediates/Unity-iPhone.build/Debug-iphoneos/Unity-iPhone.build/Objects-normal/armv7/test.LinkFileList -dead_strip -all_load -weak_framework CoreMotion -weak-lSystem -fobjc-link-runtime -miphoneos-version-min=2.2.1 -framework Foundation -framework UIKit -framework OpenGLES -framework QuartzCore -framework OpenAL -liconv.2 -liPhone-lib -framework AudioToolbox -framework CFNetwork -framework MediaPlayer -framework CoreLocation -framework SystemConfiguration -weak_framework iAd -framework CoreMedia -framework CoreVideo -framework HelloUnity -weak_framework AVFoundation -framework CoreGraphics -weak_framework CoreMotion -weak_framework GameKit -o /Users/LabInnovation/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Unity-iPhone-akzhbmwtkcooizfaebdhmbyuhrbk/Build/Products/test.app/test
```

And I don't know why, because my framework exist and the framework's folder is not empty.
What is wrong?

Thanks,

Answer (score 1):

Since iOS does not support shared libraries, you need to make sure your framework is compiling to a static library.

I'm not sure about this part, but you may have to link against the static library and not the framework (i.e, '-framework HelloUnity' may not be good even if your framework is static.)

Answer (score 0):

I am sure that the framework has not been properly constructed. I suspect that VALID_ARCHS has not been removed from the project file when constructing the framework. also do check that build active architectures is set to NO

Comment: Do you have any more information on removing VALID_ARCHS? Why do you need to do this?

Comment: @Martin308 I am not exactly sure as I had done it a long time back, but I think it mentions what are the valid architectures to use that framework. As it is a work around to use frameworks(usually for desktop env) The framework build will have meta data stating that "The framework must be used for desktop applications" we have to modify this line so that we can use it in mobile apps.